# How to filter an array in an object in the SQL query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Assume the following classes:

```
class ParentObject {
   guid Id {get;set;}
   string SomeProp {get;set;}
   List<OtherObject> OtherObjects {get;set;}
}
```

```
class OtherObject {
   string PropA {get;set;}
   string PropB {get;set;}
}
```

I want to retrieve a collection that returns all objects ParentObj which have a at least 1 object OtherObj with PropA equal to the given search parameter.

```
myQueryable = myQueryable.Where(mq => mq.OtherObjects.Any(oo => oo.PropA.Equals(filterParams.PropA)));
```

Result:

```
{
  "parentObjects": [
    {
      "id": "someguid",
      "someProp": "someValue",
      "otherObjects": [
        {
          "propA": "abc",
          "propB": "aaa"
        },
        {
          "propA": "def",
          "propB": "bbb"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "someguid",
      "someProp": "someValue",
      "otherObjects": [
        {
          "propA": "abc",
          "propB": "bbb"
        },
        {
          "propA": "def",
          "propB": "bbb"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is, how do I extend the query so OtherObjects in the result only contains those which have PropA equal to the search parameter?
So if in my example teh search parameter would be "abc" I would like this result:

```
{
  "parentObjects": [
    {
      "id": "someguid",
      "someProp": "someValue",
      "otherObjects": [
        {
          "propA": "abc",
          "propB": "aaa"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "someguid",
      "someProp": "someValue",
      "otherObjects": [
        {
          "propA": "abc",
          "propB": "bbb"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Fetching the data like in my first example and then filtering  locally is no problem:

```
result.ForEach(r => r.OtherObjects = r.OtherObjects.Where(oo => oo.PropA.Equals(filterparams.PropA)).ToList());
```

But I would rather like to extend my LINQ query so the data which I don't need isn't fetched from the db. Assume a very large number of fields in the parentObject and otherObject so a Select to a new OtherObject is something I would really like to avoid.

Comment: I think you need [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include)

Comment: If this is Entity Framework core, please use an [ef-core-xx] tag (where xx is the version) instead of [entity-framework].